# Retreive SitePage publishingState from list query with GraphAPI

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph, sitepages

I am currently crawling through my SharePoint lists using GraphAPI in order to retrieve informations.

The request looks like the following:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/mysite.sharepoint.com,siteids/lists/listId/items?$expand=*
```

My problem is that in the case of crawling a sitepage from a list I'd like to skip unpublished pages.

At the moment I am only able to retrieve this information from the following request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/mysite.sharepoint.com,siteId/pages?$select=publishingState,id
```

That would by comparing the list item's `listItemUniqueId` and the page's`id` to skip if the matching `publishingState` is `unpublished`.

My question would be, is there a way to limit the number of requests made and join these two needs into one request?

Performance-wise, doing a request like the second one when we are aware that we are handling is far from optimal, but neither is fetching `publishingStates` for all `sitePages` in memory and checking then.

Thank you for your time, if I am too vague on any points or if there are any misconceptions on my end please let me know so I can learn more :)